# How to hide key bindings which are coming by default from Eclipse in plugin.xml?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to hide the key bindings which are coming by default from Eclipse in my DSL.
I don't need those key bindings as they are unnecessary for a DSL because they are Debug and Run related Key bindings.

[image]

Can some one please tell me how can I hide these bindings?

Comment: Well are you actually using the debug components of Eclipse? Just leave the debug plug-ins out of your RCP if you aren't.

Comment: There are some of the java files where I need this debug components.
But in DSL text editor, I don't want to see these key bindings.
So, I just want to hide them only for DSL text editor.

Comment: Since those bindings are in the "In Windows" context they would be difficult to suppress.